# Basic question for indecomposability of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading Hungerford's "Algebra", and I am new to group. In chapter 2 section 3 exercise 1, the question is  "A group G is indecomposable if and only if $G \ne \langle e\rangle $ and $G \cong H \times K$ implies $H=\langle e\rangle$ or $K = \langle e\rangle$."

I am confused of the notation for $\cong$, if it is $=$, then it means G is a internal weak direct product of H and K, then the question could be easily solved. Here it is the external product.

Now the question comes: how can $G \cong G \times K$ imply $K = \langle e \rangle$?

Can anyone disabuse for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\cong$ usually means "*is isomorphic to*" in the context of groups

Comment: So here it only means isomorphism without any more information like "internal"?

Comment: Two groups are isomorphic, denoted $G_1\cong G_2$, if there is a bijective homomorphism between them (as you probably know).  Furthermore, the internal and external direct product are equal in the case of finitely many factors.

Comment: I would translate the sentence as follows: a group $G$ is indecomposable if and only if $G$ is not the group $\langle e \rangle$ and $G$ being isomorphic to $H \times K$ implies that $H = \langle e \rangle$ or $K = \langle e \rangle$. I assume that $< e >$ denotes the unique group of a single element

Comment: Please use \langle and \rangle (as in the edited post) for subgroup generation: they are much more visually appealing than other symbols.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Does the equal of internal and external means when we meet $G \cong G_1 \times G_2 \ldots G_n$ we can prove every factors are disjoint?

Comment: Well, consider $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, for instance.  Of course, $0×\Bbb Z_2\cap \Bbb Z_2×0=(0,0)$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Back to the question I asked. So we still cannot say that $H \cap K = \langle e \rangle$ ? Then how $G \cong G \times K$ implies $K = \langle e \rangle$?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question you are trying to solve: the first paragraph of your question is about indecomposable groups. It doesn't say $G \cong G \times K$, but rather $G \cong H \times K$.

Comment: It doesn't.  Consider $G=(\Bbb Z_2)^{\infty}$.  Then $G$ isn't indecomposible.

Comment: If $G$ is finite, it will be true.

Comment: I guess it's a subtle point.  In $H×K$, we have $H$ and $K$, in the sense that we have $H×e$ and $e×K$.  They are isomorphic to $H$ and $K$, respectively.  And their intersection is trivial.

Comment: A group is isomorphic to an external direct product if and only if it is an internal direct product of two subgroups.

Comment: Your reply to my comment doesn't seem pertinent to my comment. I can only go on what you write in your question. In paragraph 3, you write $G \cong G \times K$, not $G \cong H \times K$, making me think you have misunderstood the question. (Note that as Chris Custer points out, it is possible for $G$ to be isomorphic to the product $G \times K$ where $K$ is non-trivial. Even for finite groups, you can't conclude that if  $A \times B \cong C \times D$ then $A \cong C$ and $B \cong D$, which is how you seem to be reasoning in your comment.)

Comment: @RobArthan I am so sorry about that, I have deleted that comment. I think I should rethink about this question.

Comment: OK. No worries: I think you should concentrate on Arturo Magidin's suggestion: the question is really about something not very deep about internal product versus external products.

Comment: Thanks. From the external direct product, we can get the internal product, by the uniqueness of representing elements, we could get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$G\cong H \times K$ means there exists a bijection $\varphi:G \rightarrow H \times K$ which is a homomorphism, that is $\varphi(h_1h_2)=\varphi (h_1)\varphi(h_2).$